# DateTime.Now ou DateTime.UtcNow

Tags: c#

Qual é a diferença entre `DateTime.Now` e `DateTime.UtcNow` ?

```
DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now; // retorna {01/08/2018 18:28:15}
DateTime dateUtfNow = DateTime.UtcNow; // retorna {01/08/2018 21:28:15}
```

O relógio do meu computador está como: ***18:28*** e data ***01/08/2018***.

A diferença que eu vi foi *3 horas* a mais. Quando devo usar `Now` e `UtcNow`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `DateTime.Now` retorna a hora configurada no servidor e o `DateTime.UtcNow` retorna a hora em UTC que é o *"Tempo Universal Coordenado"*, no caso temos 3 horas de diferença justamente porque você esta rodando na sua máquina que é no Brasil e a maioria dos estados brasileiros tem como fuso horario de *"-3 horas"*, no mapa no link do Wikpedia pode ver os estados do Brasil com diferentes horas:

- [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusos_horários_no_Brasil](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusos_hor%C3%A1rios_no_Brasil)

Se você configurar o teu computador para usar a zona horaria do estado do Acre provavelmente você veria uma diferença de -5 horas em relação ao `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Já ao usar o método:

```
Console.WriteLine( DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );
```

Ou:

```
Console.WriteLine( DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() );
```

**Você terá resultados iguais**, porque o método `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds` trabalha com UTC também, ou seja o *Unix Epoch* é baseado em UTC então a classe internamente provavelmente compensa o "fuso horário"

---

Imagine que você tem dois indivíduos:

- Paulo no Acre (-5 horas em relação ao UTC)
- Sofia em São Paulo (-3 horas em relação ao UTC)

Paulo envia uma mensagem para Sofia as `18:01` (horário no Acre):

> Terminei o protótipo do app, segue o link para teste - <sup>Hora: 18:01 ✓✓</sup>

A Sofia vai ver no quase no mesmo momento que foi enviado, mas para ela será `20:01` e vai responder de volta 30 minutos depois:

> Obrigado Paulo, testei o app, parece que esta dentro do combinado, aguardo a publicação na store - <sup>Hora: 20:31 ✓✓</sup>

O João vai receber no mesmo momento a mensagem, mas ele vai visualizar a mensagem como horário local dele que seria `18:31`:

> Obrigado Paulo, testei o app, parece que esta dentro do combinado, aguardo a publicação na store - <sup>Hora: 18:31 ✓✓</sup>

Ou seja, se salvar no "banco" a hora com a timezone da pessoa provavelmente daria problemas, agora se usar no seu banco hipotético UTC sem aplicar a timezone, seja com Unix-time ou pelo próprio banco ai basta no momento de ler a aplicação identificar a timezone do usuário que esta lendo a mensagem e ajustar o valor inserido no banco para a região dele.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Horário se usa UTC, saiu disso só dá dor de cabeça. Existem alguns casos que não é problema. Horário local só deveria ser usado como representação de marcação e não como ponto no tempo como horário é, hora sempre depende de contexto de quem lê. Usar hora já é difícil, bem difícil, usar errado é sempre um problema. Inclusive é comum as libs da linguagens serem ruins e quem quer fazer tudo certo tem que usar algo externo.

Comment: Obrigado @Maniero e @GuilhermeNascimento é porque agora está salvando como `DateTime.Now()` no database e estado da pessoa. O problema é na hora de mostrar para cliente, então eu devo fazer calcular timezone antes de mostrar a tela do cliente ou melhor obter timezone atual através do navegador do cliente. Estou certo ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a sua historinha está um magnífico :)

Comment: @MatheusMiranda é o que eu falei, estão muito errado, o seu caso é o mais óbvio para só usar UTC, jamais outra coisa. Na verdade tem outras implicações, mas nem conheço seu caso inteiro. O que vou repetir: quase todo mundo usa horário de forma errada e se mete em complicações que nem imagina ou percebe, a não ser que o uso seja muito básico.

Comment: muito bom, eu só mudaria "hora configurada no servidor", isso não procede em aplicações locais =]

Comment: @Maniero no C# tem como saber se o DateTime.UtcNow é verão  ou inverno ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Não, ele é universal, não existe isso em horário universal, isso é coisa de horário local. Como eu disse, mexer com hora é bem difícil, tem muito detalhe.

Comment: https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time e https://infiniteundo.com/post/25509354022/more-falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time e ñ é tudo.